# How to update a RecyclerView from another RecyclerView with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my project I have a fragment that hosts two RecylerView.
I would like to update the second RecyclerView when an item is clicked on the first RecyclerView.
When I click on an item in the CalendarAdapter, I would like the BookingAdapter to update its values. (BookinAdapter is currently empty)

**HomeFragment**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        calendarRecycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        calendarRecycleView.adapter = CalendarAdapter()


        bookingsRecycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        bookingsRecycleView.adapter = BookingsAdapter()


    }
}
```

**CalendarAdapter**

```
class CalendarAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<CalendarViewHolder>() {

    var selectedPosition = -1

    val daysList = listOf("10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28")

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return daysList.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CalendarViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_calendar, parent, false)

        return CalendarViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CalendarViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.dayLabel.text = daysList.get(position)
        holder.itemView.monthLabel.text = "DEC"

        if(selectedPosition == position)
            holder.itemView.cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008577"));
        else
            holder.itemView.cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            selectedPosition = position
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

}

class CalendarViewHolder(v: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {

    init {
        v.setOnClickListener {
        }
    }
}
```

**BookingAdapter**

```
class BookingsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<BookingsViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BookingsViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_bookings, parent, false)

        return BookingsViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BookingsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.hello.text = "Hello"

    }

    fun update() {
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
        Log.d("Log", "ok")
    }

}

class BookingsViewHolder(v: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {

    init {
        v.setOnClickListener {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a listener to your `CalendarAdapter` and listen for the clicks in the `Fragment`. Something like this:

```
 class CalendarAdapter(private val listener: CalendarItemListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<CalendarViewHolder>() {

    var selectedPosition = -1

    val daysList = listOf("10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28")

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return daysList.size
}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CalendarViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_calendar, parent, false)

        return CalendarViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CalendarViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.dayLabel.text = daysList.get(position)
        holder.itemView.monthLabel.text = "DEC"

        if (selectedPosition == position)
            holder.itemView.cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008577"));
        else
            holder.itemView.cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onItemClicked(daysList.get(position), "DEC")
            selectedPosition = position
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

}

interface CalendarItemListener {
    fun onItemClicked(day: String, month: String)
}

class CalendarViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {

    init {
        v.setOnClickListener {
        }
    }
}
```

And in you fragment implement the click listener interface and pass in to the `CalendarAdapter`.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), CalendarItemListener {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        calendarRecycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        calendarRecycleView.adapter = CalendarAdapter(this)


        bookingsRecycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        bookingsRecycleView.adapter = BookingsAdapter()


    }

    override onItemClicked(day: String, month: String){
        //update your second adapter
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I implemented this but I don't know how to update BookingsAdapter. I tried to insert `BookingsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `override fun onItemClicked (day: String, month: String)` but it doesn't update my data. Maybe it's something related to the view of the fragment?

Comment: I solved it with this: 
`override fun onItemClicked(day: String, month: String) {
        bookingsRecycleView.adapter = BookingsAdapter()
    }`
.. Do you think it's the right solution?